# Find the $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {x^2+y^4}{|x|+|y|} $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am solving this problem by using polar coordinate and I got the limit is $0$. But using polar coordinate is not enough to show that this limit does exist. I tried the paths along with $x = 0$, $y=0$ and $x=y$ but all got zero. Is there any way to get the limit of this function or proof this function does not have limit on $(0,0)$?

Comment: If you really used polar, and showed as $r \to 0$ that the expression goes to $0,$ proof is done.

Comment: Yes I know the expression goes to 0. But like I said polar coordinate is not sufficient to say a function has limit at some point. For example, $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {xy^2}{x^2+x^4}$, you can get 0 by using polar, but if you try path x=y^2, the limit is 1/2. Then this limit does not exist.

Comment: For the function in your comment in polar it is $(r^3\cos \theta \sin^2 \theta)$ divided by $(r^2 \cos ^2 \theta + r^4 \cos^4 \theta).$ Now divide top and bottom by $r^2$ and now top has a factor of $r$ but bottom doesn't, new bottom is $(\cos^2 \theta +r^2 \cos^4 \theta.)$I don't see how a zero limit follows from this. Because sometimes the cosine part in new bottom will be nearly zero, sometimes near 1.

Comment: I am sorry I wrote a typo on it, it should be $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$

Answer (score 3):

When $|x|,|y|$ small enough, we have 
$$\frac {x^2+y^4}{|x|+|y|}<\frac {x^2+y^2}{|x|+|y|}<\frac {x^2+y^2+2|x||y|}{|x|+|y|}=|x|+|y|.$$
So the limit is $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {x^2+y^4}{|x|+|y|}=0.$$